# DEPRECATION WARNING: The configuration option `config.serve_static_assets` has been renamed to `config.serve_static_files`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, linux-mint

My rails app, Rails 4.2.6, had been working perfectly but, after running the `bundle exec rails server` command as usual to start my web server for development I got this error message:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: The configuration option `config.serve_static_assets`                              
has been renamed to `config.serve_static_files` to clarify its role (it  
merely enables serving everything in the `public` folder and is unrelated 
to the asset pipeline). The `serve_static_assets` alias will be removed in 
Rails 5.0. Please migrate your configuration files accordingly. (called 
from block in <top (required)> at /home/jack/Desktop/Rails/MegsBlog/config
/environments/development.rb:2)
```

I've tried changing method names in the config files as suggested in other communities and have restarted the server but still no luck, everything in my app works except there are no images which I'm sure is due to the method name changing

Comment: In the file `/home/jack/Desktop/Rails/MegsBlog/config
/environments/development.rb` there should be on second line the old method name: `serve_static_assets`
you should change it to `serve_static_files`.

Comment: my images are still in /assets/images if that helps, ive tried moving them to the public folder but there is no change

Answer (score 2):

This might be late, but I just encountered this issue having set `config.serve_static_files = true`.
The problem was that I needed to clear the assets pipeline and precompile,so I used this command locally:
`rake assets:clean && rake assets:clobber && rake assets:precompile`.
Note that you should keep the images and all styles and javascript in `app/assets/` and not in `public/`.
I hope you have solved your problem already, or if not maybe this could help you and others, or you can share with us how you have solved it otherwise. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After updating the Rails version `serve_static_assets` method was changed to `serve_static_files`. Actually it is just a name change so you should not expect any changes of the behaviour of your app. Rename the config without changing its value and the warning will disappear.

Comment: the warning disappears but my app is still disfunctional(no images)

Comment: From your error I just saw you are using Rails 5. `config.serve_static_files = true` is coming with Rails 4 and with Rails 5 the config is - `config.public_file_server.enabled = true`. Try setting it to true and restart your server to try again.

Comment: i did that and now i get this error message in the terminal:

Comment: `/home/jack/Desktop/Rails/MegsBlog/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/railtie/configuration.rb:95:in `method_missing': undefined method `public_file_server' for #<Rails::Application::Configuration:0x0000000315ef20> (NoMethodError)
Did you mean?  public_send`